# how to get react button inside .map to work correctly?

Tags: reactjs, button

I am missing something simple but major here. I cannot get the button to just mark a favorite on the list of my stories that I have. can anyone see what I am missing?

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const MyStories = props => {
  const storyBriefs = props.stories.length > 0 ?

          addFavorite = () => {

            props.stories.map(t => (<p key={t.id}><Link to={`/stories/${t.id}`}>{t.attributes.title}</Link>

             <button onClick={this.addFavorite}>Favorite</button>

          </p>)):
          null


  return storyBriefs
 }


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    stories: state.myStories
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyStories)
```

Comment: why are you defining the `addFavorite` function there?

Comment: don't I have to? If I do not, I get undefined for addFavorite

Comment: The component is not defined correctly, could you explain what should `addFavorite` do?

Comment: I don't know you usecase. But it seems to like: you want to return a list of stories to the UI, then return the `map` function. `addFavorite` is a fn that you wish to run when clicked, then define that seperately

Comment: I had all of the above code except for the line addFavorite = () => {  and then the <button onClick={this.addFavorite}>Favorite</button>. These are a refactor I was asked to do to create a button that allows me to mark a favorite or multiple favorites along side the list that is a list of stories I have created.

Comment: I am new to just react without redux and struggling with this (I cannot use redux in the refactor)

Comment: @ChristinaW it looks like your component is connected to the redux store. From there it gets `myStories`, which is an array of stories, and also `addFavorite`, which is not currently getting but possibly is a dispatch function that dispatches an action that will modify the content of the store. Could you check if you have an action creator which is called `addFavorite`?

Comment: omg, thank you! so I am missing the action creator. But then I am using redux to create the button, right? which I am not supposed to do in the refactor. How would I create the button marking favorite without using redux here? Is it just state change, but then i am using props

Comment: Redux just handles the global state. You can then connect components to get any part of the state (and the dispatchers to modify it). But if you are not supposed to use redux then where is the data (stories) coming from? From the parent? Fetched inside the component? From a react context?

Comment: yeah, actually, I think I am just not supposed to use redux or hooks to create the button, but I just added the addFavorite action creator and it is now a different error I am getting. ./src/components/MyStories.js
  Line 11:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

   9 | 
  10 |              <button onClick={this.addFavorite}>Favorite</button>
> 11 |           </p>)):
     |                 ^
  12 |           null
  13 | 
  14 |

Comment: The component JavaScript is not correct so that is why you get errors. But before fixing it we need to understand where is `stories` and `addFavorite` coming from or how should it be defined.

Comment: okay, we are inside the component MyStories.js.  I also have an action myStories.js and reducer.

Comment: @ChristinaW - Please create a stripped down reproducible example using this: https://codesandbox.io/s/new and share the link when done. There are many errors in your example code that are preventing the component from working. To name a few: 1.) Your component conditionally returns another function or it returns null. 2.) You're using `this` inside of a function which has no lexical scope and therefore `this` is undefined. 3.) Your button should be calling an action creator and this action should be appended with `dispatch` by passing a `mapDispatchToProps` object to the `connect` function.

Comment: @MattCarlotta - My original code works, I was asked to refactor by adding a button which allows me to mark favorite next to the stories I (the person using the app) like the best. Conditions are that I only use react.js to create the button and do not use hooks or redux. The code I added to try and accomplish this was the line ```addFavorite = () => {``` and ```<button onClick={this.addFavorite}>Favorite</button>```.  I now what you are saying about "this" and how I cannot use it inside the function. My brain is just completely mush after trying so many ways to get this to work

Comment: @ChristinaW - Please create a stripped down reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/new and share the link.

Comment: @MattCarlotta   https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-vaughan-jm8cv

Comment: @MattCarlotta I can't right now, my toddler is ready for bed. I will try tomorrow. Thank you everyone for trying to help